# Java MongoDB find documents by mail regex

Tags: java, regex, mongodb-query

I am writing some application where I want to find all employees who are using yahoo's mail. My code is below and is not working as it should. What would be simplest way to do it?

```
public static void findAllEmplyestUsingYahooMail(){
        try {

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
            DB database = mongoClient.getDB("employeeDB");
            DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("employeesCollection");

            BasicDBObject regexQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            regexQuery.put("mail", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^@yahoo.com")
                .append("$options", "is"));

            DBCursor cursor = collection.find(regexQuery);
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next());
            }


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know mongoDb but if I would bet the regex is wrong. You are saying that you want every field mail that START with `@yahoo.com`.  Try changing your regex to: `.+@yahoo.com`

Comment: Nope with .+@yahoo.com is not working. I know that . is used for any character and in my my case it shouldn't work, bacause it doesn't mater what is before @yahoo.com, is it special characters as @,!. etc or is digits or uppercase and downcase letter.

Comment: That's precisely why `.+` would work..? Since it matches everything it will be able to match any letters and/or digits etc. Since it seems like anchors are supported here, I would go for `@yahoo.com$`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it without actually executing, I think the problem is in the regex. It should be somthing like:

```
regexQuery.put("mail", new BasicDBObject("$regex", ".+@yahoo.com") ...
```

@Codemaster Did u try the same query in the mongo shell? It's working in the mongo shell.

Comment: Nope it is not working, I have tried it. I will check later some other options and I if I find answer I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try doing it like this:

```
regexQuery.put("mail", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^@yahoo.com"))
```

It would get converted to a regex query:

```
db.yourcollection.find({"name": /^@yahoo.com/})
```

Comment: This regex pattern is wrong because it is saying that it should get everything that START with `@yahoo.com`